# split a CSV file by / (forward slash) delimiter

Tags: bash, csv, split

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
IL9R/SPRY3/VAMP7

CARD19/FGD3

VAV2
```

This is the output I want:

```
IL9R

SPRY3

VAMP7

CARD19

FGD3

VAV2
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Trivially with `sed`, `sed 's|/|\n\n|g' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using just bash:

```
while read -r line; do echo "${line////$'\n\n'}"; done < file.csv

IL9R

SPRY3

VAMP7

CARD19

FGD3

VAV2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat boo
L9R/SPRY3/VAMP7

CARD19/FGD3

VAV2
```

- Using tr "/" "\n" [ replacing "/"  with newline character "\n"

```
cat boo |tr "/" "\n"
L9R
SPRY3
VAMP7

CARD19
FGD3

VAV2
```